# C atomic read modify write

Tags: c, atomic, powerpc

Are there any functions in C to do atomic read-modify-write?
I'm looking to read a value, then set to 0, in a single atomic block.

For C++ there is std::atomic::exchange() which is exactly what I'm looking for. Is there something equivalent in C?

Here's the code:

```
void interruptHandler(void) {
    /* Callback attached to 3rd party device driver, indicating hardware fault */
    /* Set global variable bit masked flag to indicate interrupt */
    faultsBitMask |= 0x1;
}

void auditPoll(*faults) {
    *faults = faultsBitMask;
    /* !!! Need to prevent interrupt pre-empt here !!! */
    /* Combine these two lines to a single read-modify-write? */
    faultsBitMask = 0;
}
```

The target architecture is PowerPC.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The C11 standard added [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). If your compiler is new enough you could use them.

Comment: C11 atomic types and operations have been specified in synch with the C++11 specification. They should be binary compatible between C and C++.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude and @JensGustedt!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `<stdatomic.h>` header contains a type-generic function [`atomic_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_exchange) that's very similar to the C++ version:

```
_Atomic int n = 10;

#include <stdatomic.h>

int main(void) { return atomic_exchange(&n, 0); }
```

Comment: This is not the whole story, atomics in the context of signal handlers need some special care. Also you really don't need atomic exchange for what you are doing, please see my answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Hm, that's what the OP asked for. She didn't say that it's for   a signal handler.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to use atomics with a signal handler. C11 atomic types can do that if they are "lock-free", but usually they are. You can test this property for `int` with `ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE`.

For your case you don't even need an atomic exchange function. On an atomic variable

```
faultsBitMask |= 0x1;
```

will always be an atomic read-modify-write operation.

Comment: would this be OS dependent? Does the language itself doesn't specify anything about cache invalidation around a signal handler?

Comment: Yes, provided the macro says that your data type is lock-free, this is platform independent.

Comment: Hi Jens, this isn't for a signal handler. The interruptHandler() is a callback from a 3rd party Broadcom SDK. It fires when the Broadcom hardware device has a fault, and indicates what fault.

Comment: @Splaty, even better, then you don't have to check for lock-free and qualifying your variable as `_Atomic` should be the only change you need to do to your code.

Comment: Hmm, I think I would still need atomic_exchange() for the read and clear right? { *faults = faultsBitMask; faultsBitmask = 0; }

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC, give the [GCC builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) `__atomic_exchange` or `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` a try.